# Can the repeated pulling of a particular muscle without time to fully heal in between injuries cause chronic pain?

Tags: chronic-pain

While i was wrestling a few years ago i pulled a muscle in my neck and the coach never gave it time to fully heal. I experience intense neck pain on occasion, just like my grandfather and dad but they didn't get it until they were older (early20's).

Comment: Instead of guessing that it's from repeated muscle strains and that your coach is at fault, have you considered asking a doctor? Intense neck pain is not normal.

Comment: @CareyGregory yeah, I know it's not normal but my doctor dismisses it as a teenager who is just exaggerating

Comment: Then find another doctor who will listen. The answer to your question is yes, repeated muscle injury can lead to chronic pain, but intense neck pain still isn't normal and I doubt muscle strains explain it.

Comment: @careygregory ok